# comparar parámetros POST con registros de Base de Datos en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, sql, crud

Al crear una reunión y hacer `submit`, recibo los siguientes parámetros por el `post` en mi controlador:

```
    $sala_sin_comprobar = $_POST['sala'];
    $fecha_sin_comprobar = $_POST['fecha'];
    $inicio_sin_comprobar = $_POST['inicio'];
    $fin_sin_comprobar = $_POST['fin'];
```

Entonces llamo al método que me va a recorrer las reuniones para comprobar si algún parámetro coincide:

```
    $reunionDao = new ReunionDAO();

    $reunionDao->comprobar_disponibilidad_reuniones($sala_sin_comprobar, $fecha_sin_comprobar, $inicio_sin_comprobar, $fin_sin_comprobar);
```

Y este es el método:

```
public function comprobar_disponibilidad_reuniones($salaProp, $fechaProp, $inicioProp, $finProp){
    $consulta=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM reunion");
    $consulta->execute();
    $reunion = new Reunion();
    $reunionDao = new ReunionDAO();
    $listaReuniones = $reunionDao->todasLasReuniones();
    foreach($listaReuniones as $reunion){

        $sala = $reunion->getSala();
        $fecha = $reunion->getFecha();
        $inicio = $reunion->getInicio();
        $fin = $reunion->getFecha();

        if ($sala == $salaProp || $fecha == $fechaProp || $inicio == $inicioProp || $fin == $finProp){
            echo "ya está elegida";
            return false;
        }
        echo "se puede";
        return true;
    }
```

El problema es que solo comprueba la primera reunión de la tabla, y yo necesito que recorra todas...

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que estas retornando una respuesta en cualquiera de las dos situaciones(haya o no haya reunión) dentro de tu foreach, osea la que se cumpla primero retornará, puedes mejor retornar un numero así veras el numero de veces que esta solicitada:

```
public function comprobar_disponibilidad_reuniones($salaProp, $fechaProp, $inicioProp, $finProp){
$consulta=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM reunion");
$consulta->execute();
$reunion = new Reunion();
$reunionDao = new ReunionDAO();
$listaReuniones = $reunionDao->todasLasReuniones();
$contador =0;
foreach($listaReuniones as $reunion){

    $sala = $reunion->getSala();
    $fecha = $reunion->getFecha();
    $inicio = $reunion->getInicio();
    $fin = $reunion->getFecha();

    if ($sala == $salaProp || $fecha == $fechaProp || $inicio == $inicioProp || $fin == $finProp){

        $contador++;
     }
   }
   return $contador; //fuera del foreach
 }
```

Si el numero que retorna es cero entonces nunca entro al bloque if